# How to run the test cases category wise I have tried with mstest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, automated-tests, mstest

Hi I have wrote test cases under one class in visual studio 2013. 
can I run the test cases through the automation by category wise as each class contain more than 50 test cases and I don't want to run whole at a time wanted to run by category wise, I have tried with the mstest but it gives me no test to execute.

mstest /testcontainer:D:\TFS\OTests.dll /category:Tests

Do anybody can suggest me something else as m not able to do that..

Comment: How do you add the test category info in your class? Can you share some sample?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Hi I wrote the classes and added different methods in it, I have test1(12) test2(10) test3(14) test4(2) test5(10) in the Test Explorer so wanted to execute only test2(10) ...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error message or other logs for further troubleshooting?

Anyway, please make sure you creating and Assigning Test Categories correctly.

Please refer to this article for details:

[How to: Group and Run Automated Tests Using Test Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683(v=vs.120).aspx)

---

**UPDATE1:**

Please exactly following the rules, you need to add the quotes for the Category name.

Please try `mstest /testcontainer:D:\TFS\OTests.dll /category:"Tests"`

---

**UPDATE2:**

I tested at my side, everything works correctly. Please see the sample: ( You need to run the command with **VS2013 Cross Tools command Prompt** window)

```
        [TestCategory("nine"), TestMethod()]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }

        [TestCategory("eight"), TestMethod()]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 2);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I get "no test to execute" I have tried with the Writing Power Shell Script also but there also same Issue

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Please try "mstest /testcontainer:D:\TFS\OTests.dll /category:"Tests" "

Comment: I have tried this also and giving me same error "No test to execute". I do have some non Public classes was it because of that ?

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Please see the sample in the updated answer, you need to run the command with VS2013 Cross Tools command Prompt window, If that still not work for you , please share your code here for further troubleshoot.

Comment: @ Andy-MSFT
namespace TESTNEW
    { 
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClass]
    public class NewTests : BaseTest 
   { 
 [Test, Order(010), Category("Sale"), Category("NewSale")]
        public void Display()
        {
            try
            {
            }
 }
 [Test, Order(020), Category("Sale"), Category("NewSale")]
        public void Verification()
        {
            try
            {
            }
 }
 
}

Comment: @Andi-MSFT I do have in the NewTest Class different different testcases and wanted to run NewTest the BaseTest

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Still cannot understand that very well, could you please post your entire code on your original question (edit and copy/paste the code). or package your test project then [upload it to OneDrive](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Upload-photos-and-files-to-OneDrive-b00ad3fe-6643-4b16-9212-de00ef02b586) and share the package link here. Thus we can get the project for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Andi-MSFT can i have your Email Address so that I can forward you the Query and the Code as I don't have access to OneDrive now...

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Sorry, that's not allowed with the company policy. You can sign up OneDrive easily, or you can upload to any other site which we can access to.

Comment: @Andi-MSFT 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B30wQkng86mBb0pfaFR0SkRvWEU/view

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B30wQkng86mBSWVKUUZPWmljbVE/view

Wanted to Run AccountGroupTests in image

Comment: @Andi-MSF Please find bellow Link for code and image 

https://ufile.io/gw927

https://ufile.io/f14q7

Comment: @Andi-MSFT Hi Andi any solution which you can give me... I have tried things but not worked for me

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Sorry, I have no idea for that, seems you referenced  the third test framework. For category test, you have to set the category following the rules, but in your code, I can't understand the structure.